# Android - Exit toolbar while scrolling viewpager

Tags: android, xml

I have to exit toolbar when scrolling in my activity .

I have this activity :

[image]

How can i add this feature to activity ?

My activity XML code :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:background="?colorPrimary"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/background"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: Have a look at this blog post: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html and this demo-app: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add following scroll flags to Toolbar:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

And layout_behavior to ViewPager

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Inside viewPager views, it's children must be scrollable, otherwise it won't work.

and the parent layout that includes the toolbar should be CordinatorLayout, Example is shown below

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
   android:id="@+id/viewPager"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: what you mean `children must be scrollable` ?

Comment: @Ghorbanzadeh Whatever you are showing inside each page of viewPager should be scrollable. (like using  Recylerview or Listview or scrollview)

Comment: @Ghorbanzadeh can you paste your full xml file to see what has went wrong

Comment: @Ghorbanzadeh i have updated my answer, you can check it